# Clean shutdown of Spring WebSockets STOMP client

Tags: java, spring, websocket

A [Spring WebSocket STOMP client sends a `long` to Spring WebSocket STOMP server](https://github.com/JanStureNielsen/spring-websocket-ping/tree/keepalive) that immediately returns the same value. When the client completes sending, it exits its main thread and the client terminates as expected.

If I [enable STOMP heartbeats](https://github.com/JanStureNielsen/spring-websocket-ping/blob/keepalive/client/src/main/java/sample/spring/websocket/client/Application.java#L90-L91):

```
webSocketStompClient.setTaskScheduler(
    new DefaultManagedTaskScheduler()
    );

webSocketStompClient.setDefaultHeartbeat(
    new long[] {10_000, 10_000}
    );
```

the client no longer exits the JVM when the client's main thread finishes because the `DefaultManagedTaskScheduler` task-scheduler started a non-daemon thread ("pool-2-thread-1").

I don't want to exit via `System.exit`, so how can the keep-alive task-scheduler be shutdown so the client terminates when the main thread finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Build and keep the JDKs executor and shut down the executor when finished.

**Details**:

```
public class MyTaskScheduler {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    private final ConcurrentTaskScheduler scheduler;

    public MyTaskScheduler() {
        executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduler = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler(executor);
    }

    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return scheduler;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }

}
```

In the appropriate context, construct and keep the new task-scheduler:

```
MyTaskScheduler myTaskScheduler = new MyTaskScheduler();
```

And use the new task-scheduler instance for heartbeats:

```
webSocketStompClient.setTaskScheduler(
    myTaskScheduler
    );

webSocketStompClient.setDefaultHeartbeat(
    new long[] {10_000, 10_000}
    );
```

When application is finished shut down the executor:

```
myTaskScheduler.shutdown();
```